# How to highlight weighted nodes in r?

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to programming, and brand new to R. I'm struggling to figure out how to highlight a weighted node. I have a data frame for example like so:

```
a   b
a   c
a   d
e   f
g   h
i   j
```

so a connects to 3 things, while the others in the first column only connect to one. How do I graph this so that it algorithmically recognizes that "a" has the higher weight and highlights it.

This is my first question ever on here so forgive the format.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used the `igraph` package for building and plotting graph data structures?

Comment: "algorithmically"; "highlights" => please define

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using one out of many possible weighting schemes (the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory))):

```
df <- read.table(text="a   b
a   c
a   d
e   f
g   h
i   j")
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
coords <- layout.auto(g)
# "weight" nodes by number of edges and rescale values from 10 to 20:
V(g)$size <- plotrix::rescale(degree(g), c(10, 20))
plot(g, layout=coords, vertex.size=V(g)$size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use brighter colors to (change hue, use some shades palette or increase alpha value), here is one example:

```
df <- read.table(text="a   b
                 a   c
                 a   d
                 e   f
                 g   h
                 i   j", header=FALSE)
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
deg <- 1 + degree(g, mode='out')
plot(g, vertex.size=10*deg, 
     vertex.color=colorRampPalette(c('grey','green'))(max(deg))[deg])
```

[image]